# Android: where to find xhdpi menu icons?

Tags: android

I use menu icons provided in the android sdk, like the the info icon below.  All the platforms prior to version 14 provided these in ldpi, mdpi, and hdpi.  Platforms 14 and 15 provide xhdpi icons, but they no longer include the menu icons (because they have been replaced with actionbar friendly icons).

So, is there somewhere that the old menu icons are published in xhdpi sizes?

[image]

Edit:

The below link is helpful.  The provided clipart includes some of the icons I need, which can then be exported to xhdpi.  But I still am missing a couple the "ic_menu_compose.png" icon.

http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/icons-menu.html#source.space.trim=1&source.space.pad=0&name=example

Comment: xhdpi was introduced in Gingerbread (API level 9), so if it exists it would be between those points. What's the filename for the lower density version?

Comment: I looked in 9,10,11,12, and 13 -- none of which included any xhdpi icons.  There are a few icons I'm looking for, the example I included was "ic_menu_info_details.png". "ic_menu_compose.png" would be of particular usefulness.

Comment: There's a set here: http://android.yongbok.net/repository/frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-xhdpi/ but they are of a different graphical style. Graham's answer is probably correct - after all, it could well have been in those APIs purely for developer facilitation rather than ever specifically catered for by the OS' graphics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you will find the answer to this is no.

The reasoning for this is that tablet computers are the real targets of xhdpi (due to their screen size) and they are a newish addition to Android hardware on the whole. Tablet's  started on Android 3.0 (API 11) and new ones will (hopefully) come out with ICS which uses a higher API level. As you said yourself the actionbar uses smaller icons so that eliminates a few more possibilities.

My answer: use Paint.NET or Photoshop and enlarge said icon or make another.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the source of the new Action icons [here](http://developer.android.com/design/static/download/action_bar_icons-v4.0.zip). Then apply the style found in the [UI Guidelines](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_menu.html#style9) using Photoshop.

It's not exactly what you're asking for, but I hope it helps. This would probably be a useful thing to others, if you end up doing it yourself, and feel like sharing.